# Search for messages with a particular threadId in Gmail API

Tags: search, gmail, message, gmail-api

Using the new gmail api (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) I'd like to search for messages with a particular threadId.

My use case is that I'd like to find all messages on a thread that don't have an attachment and aren't a draft. Instead of fetching all the messages in a thread using thread.get and then inspecting each message to check if its a draft or has an attachment (non trivial), I'd rather just issue the query on messages.list of "-has:attachment -is:draft threadId:FOO".

Although I can't seem to find how to specify a threadid when executing a search. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Supports the same query format as the Gmail search box." ( from: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list )

The search query format supported by the Gmail search box is documented here:
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en

(Short answer is that's not supported.)

Answer (score 3):

Google actually provides an API for retrieving a list of messages with any given thread ID. So if you already have the ThreadID, why not just tap into this API?

Not sure what language you are using, but in .NET it can be done like this:

```
var threadMessages = gService.Users.Threads.Get("me", "*YourThreadID*").Execute();
```

where gService is the GmailService that you would have previously created. So why not just call that an iterate through the messages in the thread checking for those with attachments etc?

Some quickstart documentation for setting this up can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet)

Comment: that just returns all the message ids and not the messages themselves which i need to check if they have attachments.

Comment: Once you have the messageID you can easily retrieve the message details like so - 

var messageDetails = gService.Users.Messages.Get("me", message.Id).Execute();

messageDetails will now contain the details of the message for the ID you've provided. You can then have a look in this object and find the attachments - I'd have a look at this section in the object: messageDetails.Payload.Parts

Let me know if this helps.